# virtualenv v16.7.2 powershell activate script: "You must 'source' this script: PS> . .\ENV\Scripts\activate" error

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10, virtualenv

## The Problem

Newest version of virtualenv (16.7.2) on python v.3.7.4 has 4 additional lines for the "activate.ps1" script, which when run on Windows10 powerhsell gives the error: `You must 'source' this script: PS> . .\ENV\Scripts\activate`
How do I fix this? (please note that I have read and done all that was mentioned on the other forum questions as well as the manual for virtualenv related to windows and powershell.)

## Steps I took / things tried:**

I have set the execution policy to RemoteSigned (as recommended in other forums):

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

When I want to activate virtualenv, I run `.\ENV\Scripts\activate`

## Where the problem is

The problem is with lines 3 to 6 of the activate.ps1 script that is auto generated by virtualenv when you make a new virtual environment:

```
if (@($null,"Internal") -notcontains $myinvocation.commandorigin) {
    Write-Host -Foreground red "You must 'source' this script: PS> . $($myinvocation.invocationname)"
    exit 33
}
```

It seems that `$myinvocation.commandorigin` is set to **Runspace** instead of *Internal*

## Question

How do I fix this? Any ideas? Thanks :)))
Note that I don't want to manually adjust every auto-gen `activate.ps1` file.

Comment: As the message says - dot-source the script: `. .\ENV\Scripts\activate` (notice the extra `.` in front)

Comment: wow! That worked! I'm not familiar with PS, so I don't particularly know why that worked? (hence I never noticed the extra dot haha)
Also please add that as answer so I can choose it as the solution :)

Comment: @ffarhour When you run the script as you did, the things that happen in `activate` remain in the scope of the script. It is only when you source it (via `.` or `source`) that the changes are applied _outside_ the scope of the script (i.e. in your shell environment). That is generally the case for any script, and it applies to all sorts of shells like PS, bash, zsh, etc.

Comment: @brentertainer I see, thanks

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Please post that as a solution so I can +1 it.

Comment: @plum0 Your wish has been granted!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's have a look at that error message:

> `You must 'source' this script: 
>   PS> . .\ENV\Scripts\activate`

Hmmmm... - `PS>` is probably just the prompt, which leaves us with this:

```
  . .\ENV\Scripts\activate
# ^
# |
# Check out this guy
```

That, the lonely `.` in front of the path, that is the *dot-source operator* in powershell.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#dot-sourcing-operator-), it:

> Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions, aliases, and variables that the script creates are added to the current scope.

I haven't had a look at `virtualenv`, but I assume it'll want to define a number of variables and to ensure that these persist after the script has run, it needs to be run in the current scope.

So this is the *literal* command you have to run to fix it:

```
. .\ENV\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced this issue. To solve this I created a new virtualenvironment as follows:

```
python -m venv directory-name
```

To activate:

```
Scripts>./activate
```

And Now it's working fine...

Comment: i had a similar situation; had to delete a previous install of venv that just wouldn't get past the "You must 'source' this script:" message. Once i reinstalled with the python -m venv [dir-name] it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Screenshot attached for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPyFE.png)
I've just encountered the same issue but I did the following:

1. Create a new virtual environment;

   `python -m venv directory`
2. Navigate into the newly created directory;

   `cd directory`
3. Activate the virtual environment.

   `.\Scripts\activate`

This resolved my problem. I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I Also Faced the same issue solved it by using this :

Created A Virtual Environment By : 
    virtualenv environment

After Creating Virtual Environment

I activated it by using :

```
source environment/bin/activate
```

And It activated my Virtual Environment

Answer (score 0):

1. I created new, virtualenv as follows:
2. python -m ven directory name.
3. cd to the the created directory.
4. Then I activated the directory as usual.